# Maven - Querying a dependency for information at compile time

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using Maven for one of our projects. We have a compile-time plugin, `jasperreports-plugin`, that is built using `jasperreports` `6.1.1`. However, we  have another dependency (which we control), `jasper-including-artifact`, that uses `jasperreports` `6.1.0`. This requires us to manually override the version of the `jasperreports` in the  section for the `jasperreports-plugin` so they match up. What the POM ends up looking like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-including-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.alexnederlof</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works, but to make it more maintainable we'd ideally like to be able to read a value from our `jasper-including-artifact` dependency and use that to set the version of the overriding dependency in `jasperreports-plugin`, so we don't need to make manual modifications to the POM when the version of `jasperreports` in `jasper-including-artifact` is changed. So something like this (obviously fake):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-including-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.alexnederlof</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasper-including-artifact.jasper-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that it's not the version of the `jasper-including-artifact` we're interested in, but the version of `jasperreports` contained inside it. We control `jasper-including-artifact` so we can make changes to the POM for that if required.

Is this a capability that Maven offers?